# Imagick is displaying blank images with php

Tags: php

I installed imagick and checked to make sure the class exists etc. I can get it to count images in tiffs and other things. However, I cant get it to display an image. I am using the following code :

```
header('Content-type: image/JPG');

$image = new Imagick(' ur to my jpg here ');

$image->thumbnailImage(100, 100);

echo $image;
```

But it displalys a blank image. When I look at the HTML code produced I get this:

```
<html>
<body style="margin: 0px;">
<img style="-webkit-user-select: none" src=" url to this page imagechange.php">
</body>
</html>
```

Can anyone explain why the image is not being displayed? Above the HTML appears the image src as the PHP page that I am using and not the image.

Comment: Have a look at the error log, there is most likely a error somewhere, missing module, bad configuration or anything else.

Comment: Try changing content type to `image/jpeg`

Comment: THanks hank, sorry to be a pain but how would I check the error log im not exactly a php expert yet

Comment: remove the header() line temporarily and instead add error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 'On'); and it may tell you in your browser.

Comment: I think, you have checked the Font Color, sometime it happens that Font Color and background Color Mix it up. So Blank Image visible